# How can i apply these arguments to my python function?

Tags: python, function

If you get three sticks, there is no guarantee that you can form a triangle with them. For example, if one of the sticks has a length of 25 centimeters and the other two are only one centimeter long, there is no way that the two short sticks will touch in the middle.
There is a simple test to find out if it is possible to form a triangle with the three given side lengths:

If one of the three side lengths is greater than the sum of the other two, you cannot build a triangle with it. If one of the three side lengths is greater than the sum of the other two, you cannot construct a triangle. (If the sum of two side lengths is equal to the third one, the result is a so-called >>degenerated<< triangle.)

Write a function with the name ist_dreieck, which accepts three integers as arguments and answers with Yes or No to the question whether you can form a triangle with the corresponding side lengths.

Write a function that prompts the user to enter three side lengths, converts them to integers, and then checks with ist_dreieck whether a triangle can be formed.

well here is what i tried till now:

```
a = 25
b = 1 
c = 1 
sum = a+b+c

if a or b or c > sum:
    print("triangle cannot be built")

else:
    print("triangle can be built")
```

Comment: all I've done is start the function and used the input. but i think its wrong. 

def ist_dreieck():
    input ("yes", "no")

Comment: python or basic?

Comment: not basic, but python

Comment: Please don't tag your Python questions [tag:basic]. BASIC is another programming language.

Comment: my bad, i am new to the programming world. so my knowledge is limited within this sphere but thank you for informing me.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the logic from your question into code, we get something like the following:

```
def ist_dreieck(a,b,c):
    # Find the largest element out of a, b and c.
    largest = max(a, b, c)

    # Get the sum of the other elements
    sum_others = sum([x for x in [a,b,c] if x < max(a,b,c)])

    # If the largest element is less than or equal to the sum of the others,
    # then the triangle can be built -
    if (largest <= sum_others):
        return "triangle can be built"

    # Otherwise, it can't be built.
    else:
        return "triangle cannot be built"
```

**Example output:**

```
>>> print(ist_dreieck(25,1,1))
triangle cannot be built
>>> print(ist_dreieck(25,15,16))
triangle can be built
```

Hope that helps.

**Your current code:**

```
a = 25
b = 1 
c = 1 
sum = a+b+c

if a or b or c > sum:
    print("triangle cannot be built")

else:
    print("triangle can be built")
```

This will always print `triangle cannot be built` - because you are actually checking if `a` is not `0` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)) because of how you have constructed your if statement. The statement should read:

```
if a > sum or b > sum or c > sum:
```

But even then, the logic is flawed. Try to read through the given algorithm and compare it with your logic.